# Computational limit reached for an integral equation calculation

Tags: integral-equations

I have trouble running a calculation without getting an error,

I have the given Fredholm equation:

[image]

where $\psi(x)=\sin x$and $K(x,y)=\cos(x/2-3y)$

Now I calculated that for the operator to be a contraction, $\lambda<\sqrt{2}$.  Further, I have initial conditions that $\phi(0)=0$

So I have to solve the integral equation with the given parameters and plot the iterated solutions $f_1, f_2...f_{50}$. The form of this is , with $A$ being the Fredholm operator:

[image]

This means I have to find the plots of the iterated solutions which should converge to the solution, with a given value of lambda in that domain.

My attempt:

```
psi[x_]=Sin[x];
K[x_,y_]=Cos[x/2 -3 y];


\[Lambda]=1

PHI = DSolveValue[\[Phi][x] == 
    psi[x] + \[Lambda] Integrate[K[x, y] \[Phi][y], \[Phi[0]]==0 {y, 0, x}], \[Phi], x]
```

and

```
 Plot[
     Table[
       Callout[PHI[x], NumberForm[\[Lambda], {5, 3}]],
       {\[Lambda], -1, 4, 0.7}] // Evaluate,
     {x, 0, Pi/2},
     AspectRatio -> 1]
```

However, I get "Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in [Phi][0]==0."

and a blank plot.

Any idea how I can improve this code? I was thinking maybe I should use Picard iteration?

I add the question as a picture:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Looks buggy to me - `ϕ[x]` shouldn't appear anymore in the solution of the differential equation. Playing around a bit, I am not sure Mathematica can solve this kind of equation (the issue seems to be that the integration bound depends on `x`)

Comment: If you change the upper limit in the integral to say 4, or any number, it works. It is the variable in the upper limit that is not accepted, unless you keep the variable x in the upper limit and change psi[x] to some constant.

Comment: It was from an older version of the code, but it is superfluous, and its presence does not change the outcome.

Comment: @Vangsnes Yeah, I noticed that a constant bound works - with this in mind, are you sure your equation is correct? It seems quite unusual to have both the integrand and the integration limit depend on `x`

Comment: @LukasLang I added an update

Comment: I am very confused by your update - how does $\phi(0)=0$ relate to the equation you show at the top? Where do the $f_1,f_2,...$ come from? What is $A$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140666/discussion-between-vangsnes-and-lukas-lang).

Comment: Please keep it simple and go back to the original version of your question. You introduced new symbols ($a$ and $f$ and $A$) and a new topic (iteration) and the question is now very confusing.

Comment: The question is to find an approximation to the solution of that integral equation using those conditions. f and A are respectively the approximated solutions, and the Fredholm operator. a is not added to the question anywhere I can see.

Comment: Using: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577945/how-to-solve-a-fredholm-equation-with-known-lambda we have: `DSolve[f[x] + 3 Sin[x] + 8 \[Lambda] f[x] Sin[(5 x)/2] + 4 f''[x] == 
  4 \[Lambda] Cos[(5 x)/2] f'[x], f[x], x]`,but **Mathematica** can't solve. **Maple** can solve gives solution by define integral with **HeunC** function,but can be found a closed-form solution

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk . I update the question with the text which describes this, perhaps better than I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goal is to solve
$$f(x) = \sin x +  \lambda \int_0^x \cos(x/2-3y) f(y) dy$$

One can solve this by rewriting it as a differential equation. Define
$$u(x) = \int_0^x \cos(x/2-3y) f(y) dy$$
$$v(x) = \int_0^x \sin(x/2-3y) f(y) dy$$
They satisfy the following initial value problem:

```
eq = {
       u'[x]==Cos[5*x/2]*(Sin[x]+lambda*u[x])-1/2*v[x],
       v'[x]==-Sin[5*x/2]*(Sin[x]+lambda*u[x])+1/2*u[x],
       u[0]==0,
       v[0]==0
};
```

This computes the solution $f(x) = \sin x + \lambda u(x)$ numerically:

```
solvef[lambdaval_,xmax_] := Block[{lambda=lambdaval},
    Sin[x]+lambda*u[x] /. NDSolve[eq,{u,v},{x,0,xmax}][[1]]];
```

Plot:

```
With[{xmax=Pi/2,lambdas=Range[-1,4,0.7]},
  With[{sols=Table[solvef[lambda,xmax],{lambda,lambdas}]},
    Plot[sols,{x,0,xmax},PlotLabels->Map["\[Lambda]="<>ToString[#]&,lambdas],
         AxesLabel->{"x","f(x)"}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks , I will study your solution in detail tomorrow!

Comment: PS  link to the Picard soln https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2016/02/27/exact-and-approximate-solutions-of-the-abel%e2%80%93volterra-equations/